# Reading method invocation arguments using ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

When vising  method instruction `a.doAnother(account.getId);` Using `visitMethodInsn()` in `ASM`. I need to get type of account from the method argument `account.getId()` and the type of account is `Account`.  however I am getting return type of `account.getId()` that is `long` .
How to get Type of account that is `Account` here?

Comment: ASM can't help you with that. You should probably refactor your `doAnother` method to take an `Account` instead of a `long id`.

Comment: If the id is received from a method call, you would need to parse the privious visitMethodIns.

Comment: Hello @Clashsoft, I am processing the code of other existing project using ASM so I can not modify the doAnother() method (method of existing project) and I don't have choice other than ASM. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Hello @Rafael Winterhalter, Type of the id that is 'long' is received.  If you are asking to parse privious 'visitMethodInsn()' calls, then I think I will not get details of required method call 'a.doAnother(account.getId);'. previous method calls will give other (previous) instruction details. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: I would suggest you to clarify what your "type" is. Is it a Java class(`java.lang.Class`), a class name (`Class.getName()`), asm type (`org.objectweb.asm.Type`), java type (`java.lang.reflect.Type`) or some account type indicator (possibly `Account.getType()`)?

Comment: Account is an entity. type of Account is javax.persistence.Entity.  account is an object of type Account (entity)